# Computing recurrences

Tags: elementary-number-theory, math-software

This is probably a very simple to solve question, but i do not know how to use Pari gp to find the succesive $z(n)$ and $y(n)$ values of , for instance, the  recurrence :

`(z(0),y(0))=(1,0); z(n+1) =15z(n) +112y(n); y(n+1) = 2z(n) + 15y(n)`

What a simple line of code to use ?

Comment: I don't know about Pari, but you could [try haskell](http://tryhaskell.org):
`let z 0 = 1; z n = 15 * z (n-1) + 112 * y (n-1); y 0 = 0; y n = 2 * z (n-1) + 15 * y (n-1) in map (\n -> (z n,y n)) [0..10]` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You have a system of recurrences:
$$
y(n + 1) =  15 y(n) +  2 z(n) \\
z(n + 1) = 112 y(n) + 15 z(n)
$$
$y(0) = 0$, $z(0) = 1$.
Define ordinary generating functions:
$$
Y(x) = \sum_{n \ge 0} y(n) x^n \\
Z(x) = \sum_{n \ge 0} z(n) x^n
$$
By the properties of ordinary generating functions:
$$
\frac{Y(x) - 0}{x} = 15 Y(x) + 2 Z(x) \\
\frac{Z(x) - 1}{x} = 112 Y(x) + 15 Z(x)
$$
This gives:
$$
Y(x) = \frac{2 x}{1 - 30 x + x^2} \\
Z(x) = \frac{1 - 15 x}{1 - 30 x + x^2}
$$
Split this into partial fractions, and you have two geometric series apiece:
$$
Y(x) = \frac{1}{4 \sqrt{14}} \cdot 
         \left(
           \frac{1}{1 - x / (15 - 4 \sqrt{14})}
             - \frac{1}{1 - x / (15 + \sqrt{14})}
         \right) \\
Z(x) = \frac{1}{4 \sqrt{14}} \cdot 
         \left(
           \frac{56 - 15 \sqrt{14}}{15 - 4 \sqrt{14}}
              \frac{1}{1 - x / (15 - 4 \sqrt{14})}
             - \frac{56 + 15 \sqrt{14}}{15 + 4 \sqrt{14}}
                  \frac{1}{1 - x / (15 + \sqrt{14})}
         \right)
$$
From here you can read the coefficients:
$$
y(n) = \frac{1}{4 \sqrt{14}}
         \left(
            (15 - 4 \sqrt{14})^n - (15 + 4 \sqrt{14})^n
         \right) \\
z(n) = \frac{1}{4 \sqrt{14}}
         \left(
            \frac{56 - 15 \sqrt{14}}{15 - 4 \sqrt{14}} (15 - 4 \sqrt{14})^n 
              - \frac{56 + 15 \sqrt{14}}{15 + 4 \sqrt{14}} (15 + 4 \sqrt{14})^n
         \right)
$$

Comment: Moral: if you want computer code as an answer, then ask in a computer forum, not in a math forum.

Comment: @GEdgar, guilty as charged. In my defense I'll say that the algebra was done by maxima.

Comment: Moral of your Moral; Edgar: You should have said this in a literature forum; i first thought in philosophy, but let´s call only literature what pretending to be a moral, is just, though legitime, a wish to say and break silence.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the way to do it, using vectors:

$ a=10;z=vector(a);y=vector(a);z[1]=1;y[1]=0;for(n=2,a,z[n]=15*z[n-1]+112*y[n-1];y[n]=2*z[n-1]+15*y[n-1];print([z[n],y[n]]))
[15, 2]
[449, 60]
[13455, 1798]
[403201, 53880]
[12082575, 1614602]
[362074049, 48384180]
[10850138895, 1449910798]
[325142092801, 43448939760]
[9743412645135, 1302018282002] $